# Методы в классе с логикой другого класса должны быть статическими?

Tags: java

Например есть класс Human, у него есть некоторые поля, но действий которые он может выполнить очень много и нужно отделить его поведение в другой класс с логикой HumanLogic, можно ли эти действия там делать static методами? Если нет то как ими воспользоваться не создавая объекта HumanLogic?

Comment: проблема не в том, что вы не можете сделать все методы статическими, это возможно и это даже будет работать. но очень скоро вы столкнетесь минимум с 2 проблемами: 1)ваш код исключительно процедурный, ведь на статике не работает наследование, а, следовательно и полиморфизм вместе со всей парадигмой ООП; 2) раз все ваши методы статические, то любой метод может вызвать любой другой метод и так до бесконечности(в отличии от объекта, где нужна ссылка), угадайте, как скоро вы потеряетесь в цепочке таких вызовах. Что касается создания объекта, я не вижу здесь проблемы. поэтому вопрос:что смущает вас?

Comment: То есть если мне необходимо создать класс с логикой для какого-то класса, нужно будет создавать объект класса логики как поле в классе которому эта логика необходима? Или нужно будет просто создавать объект там где будут происходить какие либо взаимодействия с классом?

Comment: в данном случае у вас 2 варианта:1)писать логику в методах класса, где хранится его состояние (есть поля), что соответствует паттерну GRASP "Information expert"; 2) выносить логику в отдельные классы, что соответствует паттерну Service layer, по сути эта мода пришла со спрингом. А какой способ выбирать, зависит от архитектуры приложения. К примеру, при использовании спринга все бины по дефолту синглтоны, соответственно, хорошо подходит Service layer. Если это классическое ооп, то я бы выбрал 1 вариант и ничего не делил.

Comment: То есть если мне необходимо создать класс с логикой для какого-то класса, нужно будет создавать объект класса логики как поле в классе которому эта логика необходима - этот вариант корректный, если применяете Service layer

Comment: Большое спасибо, прояснили

Answer (score 1):

Есть замечательная вещь, dependency injection)) "Правила хорошего тона"
Статические методы/классы противопоказаны, их трудно тестировать/мокать

В идеале, можно воспользоваться функциональным программированием. Кривой пример:

```
public class HumanLogic {
  public boolean solveProblem(Supplier<String> problemProvider) {
     System.out.println("Solving " + problemProvider.get() + "..." ) ;
     //stupid example
     return true;
  } 
} 

==============

public class Human {

    private final HumanLogic brain;

    //dependency injection!! 
    public Human (HumanLogic brain) {
         this.brain = brain;
    } 

    public void doSomething() {
       boolean solved = brain.solveProblems(() -> "homework") ;
        System.out.println ("Task solved? : " + solved) ;
    } 

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Human human = new Human(new HumanLogic()) ;
        human.doSomething() ;
    } 
}
```

Както так

Comment: По-моему, в ответе проигнорирована самая важная часть вопроса про "не создавая объекта". Кажется, автор знает про такое решение, но его интересуют альтернативы. Я бы добавил про singlеton, как вариант решения проблемы - так ответ будет выглядеть лучше.

Comment: @Roman да, пропустила(